# Send requests to a single html page with resources only on root path

Tags: html, nginx, url-rewriting, absolute-path

I'm trying to redirect every request on my page to a single html page like so:

- somedomain.com -> /www/somedomain.com/index.html
- somedomain.com/foo -> /www/somedomain.com/index.html
- somedomain.com/foo/bar -> /www/somedomain.com/index.html

I achieved this using nginx with the configuration like so:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Now my problem is that if I access the page with a deep url like **somedomain.com/foo/bar** the referenced **css / js / etc.** can't be accessed because it tries to get the files from **/www/somedomain.com/foo/css/style.css** instead of **/www/somedomain.com/css/style.css**

Comment: Fix `index.html` to use absolute paths to assets

Comment: Yea that would be possible, but not very nice. If I change my domain name i have to change the paths to all assets

Comment: Use `/path/to/file.css`. This will always goes to `yourserver/path/to/file.css`

Comment: OK Thanks now it works. I already tried this method but it somehow didn't work. Thank you